# how to use postgresql service in gitlab ci job

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run a rspec unit test with gitlab runner in Kubernetes. Here is the sample test job that I wrote to test it.

```
test:
  stage : tests
  tags  :
        - k8s
  image : $CI_REGISTRY/devs/$CI_PIPELINE_BASE_IMAGE
  variables:
    DATABASE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
    HOST_POSTGRES: "127.0.0.1"
    POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
  services:
    - name : $CI_REGISTRY/devs/custom-postgres:v1.0.0
      alias: postgresql
  script:
        - echo "Testing pipeline"
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
        - pg_isready --dbname="${POSTGRES_DB}" --username="${POSTGRES_USER}" --host="${HOST_POSTGRES}"
        - echo $?
        - PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} psql ${POSTGRES_DB} -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -h ${HOST_POSTGRES}-c "\dt"
        - gem intall bundler
```

The response is below.

```
$ pg_isready --dbname="${POSTGRES_DB}" --username="${POSTGRES_USER}" --host="${HOST_POSTGRES}"
127.0.0.1:5432 - no response
```

I tried to find documentation around it, but there isn't much. How can I correctly connect to the postgres instance running as a service ?

Answer (score 0):

The postgreSQL isn't running in the same container as the script so it's not accessible via loopback address 127.0.0.1. As per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#services

> The script commands in the Ruby container can connect to the PostgreSQL database at the db-postgrest hostname.

in your case the alias is postgresql so the value of variable HOST_POSTGRES should be postgresql.

Comment: Sorry, I think you missed that the GitLab Runner is inside the Kubernetes. If it was docker then the alias name can be used as the hostname. In the case of Kubernetes, all the containers are loaded into the same pod

Comment: Same pod != same container. Alias works in Kubernetes.

Comment: I know same pod is not same container. Containers running in the same pod do not get invidual IP address nor support for hostname resolution AFAIK. I found an example project someone put up in the gitlab around same issue. https://gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/test-db-service. I have already tried to connect with  the service alias name. It doesn't work either.